# Printing all the numbers of a sequence until the numbers are repeated in Java

Tags: java, sequence

I have a task for my programming (java) but it's somewhat new for me and I can't figure it out in the remaining time, we must just think about it but anyways I want to understand it before the class.
There is a sequence with A(0) = 1 , A(n) = (an-1) for A(n-1) < 27 and A(n) = 2(An-1)-53 for rest. Here we have to write a program that gives the numbers of this sequence out as long as the numbers are not getting repeated.
First I wrote this 
    package practices;

```
public class Seq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nth = new int[27];
        for (int i = 1; i <26; i++) {
            nth [i]=2*nth[i-1];
            System.out.println("The "+i+" in the sequence is equal to "+nth[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

for the first conditional part but it gives me just 0s out. 
Would love to see the complete code :/ 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You almost got it right. _Hint from your question itself: `a0= 1`_ :)

Comment: So close! Keep at it

Comment: You're mixing your notations. Did you mean to say `A(0) = 1`, `A(n) = 2 * A(n-1)` for `A(n-1) < 27` and `A(n) = 2 * A(n-1) - 53` for rest?